# Get p text, when parent is clicked. P is group with many of same class

Tags: jquery, html, css

For a function, i'm working on, I need to get the exact P text, when the parent(`.photoBackground`) is clicked. The p is used as a caption, for a gallery, so there is alot of P's with same class. I need to get the text from the one i'm clicking on. Then i want to copy that specific text, to the empty `.photoCaptionBig` class. I do already have an click function (some of the other functionalities needed it): `$('.photoBackground').on('click',function ()`. How to do so?

HTML:

```html
            <div id="lightbox_caption_container">
                <a id="lightbox"></a>
                <div class="photoCaptionEffect">
                    <p class="photoCaptionBig" style="               
    "></p>
                </div>
            </div>

<div class="itemContainer">
                        <div class="photoBackground" id="photo1">
                            <div class="photoHoverEffect">
                                <p class="photoCaption" style="               
">TextTextText</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

and CSS:

```css
.photoBackground {
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease;   
}
.photoBackground:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.938em rgba( 0, 0, 0, .7 );
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease;
}
.photoBackground:hover .photoHoverEffect {
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
    opacity: 1;
}
.photoHoverEffect, .photoCaptionEffect {
    height: 65px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 155px;
    background-color: rgba(18,18,18,0.6);
    display: -webkit-inline-box;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
}
.photoCaptionEffect {
    height: 85px;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1333;
    margin-top: 365px;  
}
.photoCaption, .photoCaptionBig {
    font-family: raleway;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    line-height: 16px;
    display: -webkit-inline-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

Thank you!

- Magnus Pilegaard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jquery if you click an object you handle the click event like so

```
$('selector').click(function() {
    //to find a p within what was clicked
    var $p = $(this).find('p');
    //if the p has a particular class
    var $p = $(this).find('p.particularClass');
    //to get the text in the p
    var $text = $p.text();
});
```

Cheers.